# Redirect after form submission cgi script

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

I wrote a simple email script in python that takes the data from a form and emails it using boto. What I need to do now is redirect the user to another page "thankyou.html" without showing any cgi output.

HTML FORM:

```
    <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/iemail.py">

                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required="required"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="" placeholder="Company Name" required="required"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required="required"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <div class="select-wrapper">
                                    <select name="category" id="category">
                                        <option value="">- Category -</option>
                                        <option value="Additional Information">Additional Information</option>
                                        <option value="Services Request">Services Request</option>
                                        <option value="Consulting Request">Consulting Request</option>
                                        <option value="Development Request">Development Request</option>
                                        <option value='Support Request'>Support Request</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u 12u$(small)">
                                <input type="radio" id="priority-low" name="priority" checked>
                                <label for="priority-low">Low</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u 12u$(small)">
                                <input type="radio" id="priority-normal" name="priority">
                                <label for="priority-normal">Normal</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u$(small)">
                                <input type="radio" id="priority-high" name="priority">
                                <label for="priority-high">High</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="12u$">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6" required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u$(small)">
                                <!--<input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy">
                                <label for="demo-copy">Email me a copy</label>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="6u$ 12u$(small)">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="human" name="human" required="required">
                                <label for="human">Not a robot</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="index.html" />
                                    <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Python Script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python2.7
    import cgi
    import html
    import boto.ses
    import cgitb; cgitb.enable() #for troubleshooting

    print("Content-Type: text/html")
    print

    def getdata():
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        name = form["name"].value
        company = form["company"].value
        phone = form["phone"].value
        email = form["email"].value
        category = form["category"].value
        message = form["message"].value

        return name, company, phone, email, category, message

    #main Program
    if __name__=="__main__":
        try:
            name, company, phone, email, category, message = getdata()
            conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
            conn.send_email(
                'admin@gmail.com',
                category,
                '%r, %r, %r, %r %r' % (email, name, company,
                                    phone, message),
                to_addresses = 'admin@gmail.com'
                )
        except:
            cgi.print_exception()
```

I only can get redirected to the output for the cgi script, I need to send customers to thankyou.html

Comment: When the form is done processing, the cgi should return an HTTP Redirect to the thankyou.html page.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.